# Simple python function problem I can't figure out

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a simple webpage where everyday at midnight it records the top 5 subreddits of the day and then shows them on  a page. However at the moment all that is popping up is "day1" whenever I launch the page.
Here is the code that I think is causing this problem.

```
day_top_five = {}
day = 0
def my_cron_job(request):
    global day_top_five
    global day
    day += 1
    UClient = uReq('https://www.reddit.com/top/')
    page_html = UClient.read()
    UClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    value = page_soup.findAll("a",{"class":"_3ryJoIoycVkA88fy40qNJc"})
    loop = 0
    result = []
    while loop <= 4:
        result.append(value[loop]['href'])
        loop += 1
    day_top_five[f'day{day}'] = result
    return HttpResponse(day_top_five, datetime.now())
```

If anyone has any ideas what is wrong with this please let me know.

Comment: So how is it meant to increment the day passed 1? I only see a single day increment outside of a loop. Do you call my_cron_job multiple times?

Comment: I may have done this wrong but I did CRONJOBS = [
    ('57 23 * * *', 'myapp2.views.my_cron_job')] in settings, however I had it running and being able to return the top 5 subreddits before I just forgot how.

Comment: It's best not to use global variables with views. It would be better for you to simply have a table or a json file or something to count days.